# Can a C# .dll that is referenced within a LabView application have access to an app.config file?

Tags: c#, dll, app-config, labview

I have a C# .dll that is referenced in a LabView application. I need the .dll to gain access to an App.config file. (So that we can use log4Net within the .dll for debugging purposes)

The problem is the entry point for this C# .dll is a LabView app and not a .NET app and as a result no "DOT_NET_APP.exe.config" exists for this .dll

I've tried "LABVIEW_APP.exe.config" just to see if it COULD log and I get nothing. No log files are created. I've also tested to ensure that the log4Net configuration is correct. (Created a dummy .net console app and tested the C# .dll)

Is there a way for a .DLL to be explicitly told where to look for its configuration file? Can I override the default behavior that causes it to look for "DOT_NET_APP.exe.config" and provide my own?

Comment: No, the something.exe.config file definitely works, as long as you've picked the right *something* and the right directory.  The log4Net .config is a very mixed blessing, I found programming the config much easier to get right.  Which of course you should consider here.

Comment: The something.exe is the main labview executable and the .config file resides in the same folder as somthing.exe. It could be that a portion of the LabView code isn't instantiating C# class that has the logging...

Comment: Or it could be that you picked the wrong exe.  LabView is the kind of program that should keep its UI separate from the machine interface.  So that closing the window doesn't kill the machine.  No idea if it does, look in Task Manager's Processes tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`AppDomain.GetData()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getdata.aspx) with the `"APP_CONFIG_FILE"` parameter to find the location of your config file.

Comment: @Hans & @ devio I used the APP_CONFIG_FILE method to post a popup window that shows where the AppDomain is looking for the config file. Thanks guys :)